# “where this : class” wrong syntax

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting, extension-methods

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T TryCast<T>(this object parent)
        where T : class
        where this : class
    {
        T child = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in parent.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            child.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name)?.SetValue(child, prop.GetValue(parent));
        }

        return child;
    }
}
```

TryCast can be used as:

> someString.TryCast< someClassToCastTo >()

but it is not constrained to only classes, as "where this : class" returns syntax error", which means that, without the "this : class" constriction, it will appear on variables like int, char, etc.

I am searching for a way to constrain the type "this object parent" to only class variables, as in my use case it would make no sense to use it on simple types like int and char.

**Note:**

It is possible to capture and restrict the parent's type like so:

```
public static T2 TryCastWorse<T, T2>(this T parent)
    where T : class
    where T2 : class
{
    T2 child = (T2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T2));
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in parent.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        child.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name)?.SetValue(child, prop.GetValue(parent));
    }

    return child;
}
```

And then use it like so:

> someString.TryCastWorse< string, someClassToCastTo >()

This is not optimal, as one has to specify the class of the calling variable, as observed in the first type in the <>, which is a string, which should be always equal to someString.

This is not intended functionality in this case as it can introduce errors in some use cases.

Comment: Are you asking the same (deleted) question again?

Comment: `where this : class`, what's `this`? Not a generic type, that's for sure.

Comment: Yes thats where the syntax error happens, please read the whole question. I am trying to achieve similar functionality to what that code would do. The issue is quite complex, and yes I am asking it again as it was brutally misunderstood last time, some even said I had a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply no. You can not constraint an argument to not be a value type unless its a generic type argument with a `class` constraint.

So you are either stuck with specifying both generic arguments or live with allowing value types and code reviewing extensively.

Comment: I suspected so. It's weird to me that "this : class" doesn't work. Thank you for taking the time to read my question, I believe you are the first to do so.

Comment: Did you mean `struct` constraint or maybe "reference type"?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a cleaner syntax to call a reflection constructor for boilerplate classes. Unfortunately if you want generic type validations, you'll need to pass them along with the `<T>` syntax to the method.

An alternative is perhaps to have all your boilerplate classes extend an abstract class that has a `ConvertTo<T>()` method:

```
public abstract class ABoilerplate {
    public T ConvertTo<T>() where T : class {
        T child = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi in typeof(T).GetFields().Where(field => !field.IsStatic))//should do validations
            fi.SetValue(
                child,
                this.GetType().GetField(fi.Name).GetValue(this));
        return child;
    }
}
public class SimpleClass : ABoilerplate {
    public int ID;
}
public class DuplicateSimpleClass {
    public int ID;
}
```

Then use like

```
SimpleClass instance1 = new SimpleClass() { ID = 1 };
DuplicateSimpleClass instance2 = instance1.ConvertTo<DuplicateSimpleClass>();
```

Comment: Well spotted, indeed this is a better solution, but in this case I was not allowed to edit the classes.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for a copy-pasta that you can use to convert from old class definitions to new ones? Sounds like a fundamental rewrite is in order of an old code base? Also, have you considered the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) if you just need to add bit more functionality?